# Guides on 3D Programming Concepts?

Tags: 3d

I'm trying to move my game development into the third dimension, but I'm having a bit of troubles understanding what I actually have to do. I've created a 2D MMORPG before using C and SDL, which wasn't too hard. But I can't seem to find any useful resources explaining how 3D programming actually works. I have a basic understanding of the vector math involved, but I just can't seem to find any clear, in-depth explanation of how everything else like lighting and shaders work. I've found plenty of code samples and such, but all of them just throw in a comment like "//Apply the lighting", which doesn't really tell me anything about what it's actually doing and why.

I'm not looking for an API-Specific tutorial; it's easy enough to learn a new API--I'm just not sure what to actually do with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are looking for a book, I highly recommend [Real-Time Rendering](http://realtimerendering.com/). I have the second edition of the book and found it be a great asset when working with 3D graphics. The book explains the innerworkings of the building blocks of 3D programming, like transforms, lighting and textures. It also explores a variety of advanced topics, including shaders, collision detection, acceleration and optimization.

The book is very light on code. It explains algorithms in depth but does not contain real code snippets. So it is very good if you want to learn how things work instead of just knowing which function to call.

Comment: would there be an equivalent book or website for 2d graphics concept? or is 2d too simple for such treatment?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to understand the concepts of 3D computer graphics and rendering tutorials will not be of much help. As you found out they teach you the API but don't help with the fundamental understanding.

You need the bible of grpahics programming:

[http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Graphics-Principles-James-Foley/dp/0201121107](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201121107)

[alt text http://introtextbooks.com/wwwstatic/gfx/cover/foley-computer-graphics-principles-and-practice-in-c-2e.jpg](http://introtextbooks.com/wwwstatic/gfx/cover/foley-computer-graphics-principles-and-practice-in-c-2e.jpg)

It does not cover any OpenGL, DirectX or shaders, just the fundamentals. But that's what you need. For example: Once you've understood how lighting works the three lines that enable lighting on OpenGL will suddenly make perfect sense.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know van Dam was a writer, much less that he was a computer graphics guru...

Comment: would this better than 'real time rendering' for a complete newbie to graphics at all?

Comment: The book teaches something about "WPF" which is a feature of a proprietary software. I would not recommend this.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you check out the [NeHe OpenGL tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/), starting with the simplest ones, and learn a little bit of OpenGL.  A good OpenGL reference (such as the [Red Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321481003), though that's maybe a bit advanced to start with) will also be a big help.

Comment: Oops just saw your post, +1 for Red Book (a.k.a. The OpenGL Programming Guide, Fifth Edition)

Comment: Oh, oops. I just saw your post too. The red book was what I learned 3D from - it does a pretty good job starting you off from scratch.

Comment: If/when you pick up a copy of the Red Book, make sure it's for OpenGL 4.0+ (dealing with shaders, not the old fixed pipeline)

Answer (score 3):

[The Red Book](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/) - it's pretty much the one source that teaches everything (beginner-intermediate) that you need to know about OpenGL. Those concepts can be moved to any other 3D library pretty easily. And this has a free online version, too!

Answer (score 2):

The standard text back "in the day" was [Foley and Van Dam](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201848406), some subjects covered there are a bit long in the tooth but the fundamental mathematics behind 3-D transformations and projections hasn't changed.

[Alan Watt's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201398559) text is also good, but isn't really an introductory book.

You might also take a look at [David Eberly's](http://www.geometrictools.com/Books/Books.html) web site, he has written several books on the subject and there is a wealth of related information to be found there as well.  Expect plenty of math.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in programming for the XBOX 360 in C# you can look at the XNA Framework.  [This website](http://riemers.net/) has tons of tutorials on XNA and I highly recommend trying it out.  Just navigate to the sidebar (on the right) and click on the 3D section.